# capturing json root object using json gem

Tags: ruby, json

I have the following:

```
test_hash = {"537da428e4b09f2bd8200b77"=>{"behavior"=>"FollowUp", "key"=>nil}}
test_j = test_hash.to_json
parse_hash = JSON.parse(test_j)
```

I would like to capture '537da428e4b09f2bd8200b77' into a variable. Having a hard time capturing it using json gem.

```
parse_hash[0]
```

Throws an exception. Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: parse_hash[0] would give you the first entry of the parse_hash array...which a json object is not. You need to get the key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do like that :

```
test_hash = {"537da428e4b09f2bd8200b77"=>{"behavior"=>"FollowUp", "key"=>nil}}
test_j = test_hash.to_json
parse_hash = JSON.parse(test_j)
p hash = parse_hash.collect { |item| item[0] }
```

See more about the collect method here : http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-collect